# How to print a human-readable version of a HSSFCellStyle (or ExtendedFormatRecord)?

Tags: java, debugging, apache-poi, hssf

I'm currently trying to debug some legacy POI/HSSF code (v.3.9) and wonder if there's something to easily debug/display the contents of a `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle` (or its inherent cumbersome `org.apache.poi.hssf.record.ExtendedFormatRecord` field)?

I couldn't find any relevant `toString()` or similar methods.

Comment: Did you try [BiffViewer](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/dev/BiffViewer.html)? Also, POI 3.9 is rather old now, there's a lot to be said for upgrading to a newer on for [a large number of bug fixes](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html)!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately this class seems to be just a command line utility, not something that can be used in code. Also, as I said, it's legacy code, I have absolutely no freedom to upgrade any external libraries. :-(

Comment: Try running BiffViewer on your file, and let us know if that kind of output is the kind you need or not. If it is, we can let you know how to reproduce it in code